# How to fix a relative path when using browserify

Tags: javascript, gulp, browserify, browserify-shim

I am trying to use browserify to compile all js files.

The issue I am having is currently with: https://github.com/amsul/pickadate.js

In: https://github.com/amsul/pickadate.js/blob/master/lib/picker.date.js

It requires a relative path:

```
require('./picker.js')
```

I assume I will run into this issue again with other files.

Once all the js files get compiled and moved to my 'dest' directory this relative path is no longer correct.

Is there a way to overwrite this so it can get the right file?

Here is my full gulp task I am currently using:

```
gulp.task('js', function () {
  var browserify = require('browserify');
  var source = require('vinyl-source-stream');
  var buffer = require('vinyl-buffer');
  var globby = require('globby');
  var through = require('through2');
  var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');
  var sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps');
  var reactify = require('reactify');

  // gulp expects tasks to return a stream, so we create one here.
  var bundledStream = through();

  bundledStream
    // turns the output bundle stream into a stream containing
    // the normal attributes gulp plugins expect.
    .pipe(source('app.js'))
    // the rest of the gulp task, as you would normally write it.
    // here we're copying from the Browserify + Uglify2 recipe.
    .pipe(buffer())
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init({loadMaps: true}))
      // Add gulp plugins to the pipeline here.
    .pipe(uglify())
    .on('error', gutil.log)
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write('./'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./dest/js/'))
    .pipe(connect.reload());

  // "globby" replaces the normal "gulp.src" as Browserify
  // creates it's own readable stream.
  globby([
    './app/js/*.js',
    './app/js/materialize/**/*.js',
    './app/components/**/*.js'
  ], function(err, entries) {
    // ensure any errors from globby are handled
    if (err) {
      bundledStream.emit('error', err);
      return;
    }

    // create the Browserify instance.
    var b = browserify({
      entries: entries,
      debug: true,
      transform: [reactify]
    });

    var browser = browser({

    });

    // pipe the Browserify stream into the stream we created earlier
    // this starts our gulp pipeline.
    b.bundle().pipe(bundledStream);
  });

  // finally, we return the stream, so gulp knows when this task is done.
  return bundledStream;
});
```

picker.js lives at: ./app/js/materialize/date_picker/picker.js

Which is the right location until I browserify and move it.